# How to forward email using Python

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, forward, gmail-imap

First, let me say, **I already know that this was asked at [Forwarding an email with python smtplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717196/forwarding-an-email-with-python-smtplib) already.**

The reason that I am posting something so closely related to that question is that I have tried using the answers to that question, I have tried changing things, I have searched Google and relentlessly monkeyed with this for about 5 hours now, and I am willing to spend a lot more time on this

-- I just thought one of you might have the answer though :)

My problem is as follows, I am trying to forward an email from my gmail to another gmail, and in running as many python script as I can to try this simple task, I still cannot figure it out.

Here is the code that I am running(this is my modified version of what was posted in the other form):

```
import smtplib, imaplib, email, string

imap_host = "imap.gmail.com"
imap_port = 993
smtp_host = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp_port = 587
user = "John.Michael.Dorian.4"
passwd = "mypassword"
msgid = 1
from_addr = "John.Michael.Dorian.4@gmail.com"
to_addr = "myotheremail@gmail.com"


# open IMAP connection and fetch message with id msgid
# store message data in email_data
client = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host, imap_port)
client.login(user, passwd)
client.select()
typ, data = client.search(None, 'ALL')
for mail in data[0].split():
    typ, data = client.fetch(msgid, "(RFC822)")
    email_data = data[0][1]
client.close()
client.logout()


# create a Message instance from the email data
message = email.message_from_string(email_data)

# replace headers (could do other processing here)
message.replace_header("From", from_addr)
message.replace_header("To", to_addr)
print message.as_string()

# open authenticated SMTP connection and send message with
# specified envelope from and to addresses
smtp = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_port)
smtp.set_debuglevel(1)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.login(user, passwd)
smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, message.as_string()) 
smtp.quit()
```

The return from the SMTP debug says everything went okay, and I know that it is sending because I tried replacing the

> smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, message.as_string())

With

> smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, 'test')

And it worked fine. It prints the message.as_string() fine, and I am at a loss as how to get it to forward the email!

It doesn't have to be with SMTP or IMAP or any of this code(though it would be nice if it was) but I would really like to figure out how to do this.

I know its possible because I managed to do it yesterday, and the computer I was working on(running Windows of course) crashed and the file was gone.

For those of you who are wondering why I do not just set google to forward everything automatically, it is because I want a script that will eventually move a large amount of mail, once.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Step through your code in a debugger. When you get to the `sendmail` line, check the values of your local variables to make sure they are what you want. If that doesn't work, add an adjacent line that sends a dummy message and see if that works. (FWIW that code looks OK on first glance.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did both of those, the dummy line worked fine and sent a line saying 'test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, the Received: headers of the original email are causing gmail to drop the message. Try removing all of them before forwarding it.

If that doesn't fix it, print out the headers and code it to remove all of the ones that would not normally be there on a newly composed message.

However, why forward this way? It would be easier to just pull from one IMAP account and push it to another IMAP account directly.

In fact you could use Mozilla Thunderbird to add both accounts and just drag and drop the messages from one to the other.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to "from one IMAP account and push it to the other IMAP account directly"? I'm doing it this way because it was all I could find on 'forwarding gmail with python'. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Open up two IMAP connections, one for each account. Use .fetch() on one connection to get the message and .append() on the other to add it to the second account. Heck, for that matter, you could just use Mozilla Thunderbird to add both accounts and drag and drop the messages between them!

Comment: Thank you so much! You are like my savior here man, thank you! That IMAP.append() works like a charm, keeping the original headers in tact and everything!

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this answer. How would you create another connection without specifying the login credentials? If you're forwarding an email by doing this, wouldn't you have to login to the new account via imap and then append the message?

Comment: Yes, you need the login and password for both IMAP connections in order "forward" (really copy) an email between them.