# Cannot forward an email with attachments using imap and smtplib

Tags: python, email, imap, smtplib

I've read [on how to forward an email using imaplib and stmplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717196/forwarding-an-email-with-python-smtplib). I grab these emails (have attachments) off of gmail, sort them and want to forward them to another email account.

My code is here, and looks very similar:

```
message.mail.replace_header("From", from_addresses)
message.mail.replace_header("To", to_addresses)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(settings.RECEIPTS_EMAIL_ACCOUNT, settings.RECEIPTS_EMAIL_PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(from_addresses, to_addresses, message.mail.as_string())
server.close()
```

However, whenever it hits the `sendmail` line on `message.mail.as_string()`, the mail, then it crashes with

```
*** AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

How can I convert this to something I can send through imaplib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail), `SMTP.sendmail()` takes a single from address, not a list.

So, try:

```
server.sendmail(from_address, to_addresses, message.mail.as_string())
```

or

```
server.sendmail(from_addresses[0], to_addresses, message.mail.as_string())
```

Similarly, `Message.replace_header` should not be passed a list. Try this:

```
message.mail.replace_header("From", from_addresses[0])
message.mail.replace_header("To", to_addresses[0])
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(settings.RECEIPTS_EMAIL_ACCOUNT, settings.RECEIPTS_EMAIL_PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(from_addresses[0], to_addresses, message.mail.as_string())
server.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's break on `message.mail.as_string()` , from and to are both one address. I made that clearer in the question just now.

Comment: In that case, the error is that you are passing a list to `replace_header()`. See my recent edit.

Comment: You were totally right, thank you so much. I cant believe I didn't find that in debugging.