# Compose a forwarded email

Tags: python-3.x, email, email-forwarding

The objective is to forward a message in Python the way recognized by email clients like Evolution, MacOS X Mail, https://mail.yahoo.com. Also I'd like to attach some text where I could explain why I did the forward and have the option to access the original message when received the forwarded message. The approach proposed in the thread [Forwarding an email with python smtplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717196/forwarding-an-email-with-python-smtplib) replacing FROM, TO headers doesn't allow to do so.
This is the function:

```
def make_fwd_msg(orig, from_, to_, orig_text=None, references=True):
    """Return the message [container] with the description of the
    forward and the ORIG message"""
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['SUBJECT'] = 'Fwd: {}'.format(orig['SUBJECT'])
    if references:
        msg['REFERENCES'] = orig['MESSAGE-ID']
    msg['FROM'] = from_
    msg['TO'] = to_
    if orig_text:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(orig_text, 'plain'))
    alt = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    alt.attach(orig)
    msg.attach(alt)
    return msg
```

The full sample is in the end. I did some testing in the aforementioned email clients. They handle forwarding differently. Therefore it is hard for me know how far I have gone from the "right" forward. Please help!

Using Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye), Python 3.9.2

The full sample

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import email
import smtplib
import argparse
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


class SMTPYahoo(smtplib.SMTP_SSL):
    PORT = 465
    HOST = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super().__init__(*args, host=self.HOST, port=self.PORT,
                         **kwds)
        self.user = os.getenv('USER_NAME_EMAIL')
        self.login(self.user + '@yahoo.com', os.getenv('YAHOO_APP_PWD'))


class SMTPGmail(smtplib.SMTP_SSL):
    PORT = 465
    HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super().__init__(*args, host=self.HOST, port=self.PORT,
                         **kwds)
        self.user = os.getenv('USER_NAME_EMAIL')
        self.login(self.user + '@gmail.com', os.getenv('GMAIL_APP_PWD'))


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="""\
Forward message using Yahoo or Gmail mail server""")
parser.add_argument('--smtp-server', choices=('yahoo', 'gmail'), type=str,
                    default='yahoo', help="""
Choose smtp server""")
parser.add_argument('message_file', type=str, help="""\
A file with the message to forward""")
parser.add_argument('--verbose', '-v', action='count', default=0)


def make_fwd_msg(orig, from_, to_, orig_text=None, references=True):
    """Return the message [container] with the description of the
    forward and the ORIG message"""
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['SUBJECT'] = 'Fwd: {}'.format(orig['SUBJECT'])
    if references:
        msg['REFERENCES'] = orig['MESSAGE-ID']
    msg['FROM'] = from_
    msg['TO'] = to_
    if orig_text:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(orig_text, 'plain'))
    alt = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    alt.attach(orig)
    msg.attach(alt)
    return msg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if 0 < args.verbose:
        print(args)
    smtp_server = (SMTPYahoo if args.smtp_server == 'yahoo' else SMTPGmail)()
    from_ = smtp_server.user
    to_ = from_.split('@')[0] + ('@gmail.com' if args.smtp_server == 'yahoo'
                                 else '@yahoo.com')
    with open(args.message_file, 'rb') as fp:
        orig = email.message_from_bytes(fp.read())
    msg = make_fwd_msg(orig, from_, to_, orig_text='<Original text goes here>')
    try:
        with smtp_server as s:
            if 2 < args.verbose:
                s.set_debuglevel(1)
            answer = input(f'from_={from_}, to_={to_} send [Y/n]? ')
            if answer in ('', 'y', 'Y'):
                s.send_message(msg)
    except (Exception, smtplib.SMTPDataError) as e:

    print(e)
```

**UPDATE**
Still have no clear picture how the forward should look like. The following version of the make_fwd_msg() seems more concise and logical (credit to [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee))

```
def make_fwd_msg(orig, from_, to_, orig_text=None, references=True):
    """Return the message [container] with the description of the
    forward and the ORIG message"""
    msg = EmailMessage()
    # msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['SUBJECT'] = 'Fwd: {}'.format(orig['SUBJECT'])
    if references:
        msg['REFERENCES'] = orig['MESSAGE-ID']
    msg['FROM'] = from_
    msg['TO'] = to_
    if orig_text:
        msg.set_content(orig_text)
    msg.add_attachment(orig.as_bytes(),
                       maintype='message', subtype='rfc822')
    return msg
```

Comment: The way most modern email clients "forward" a message is quite unsatisfactory for any serious use. If your use case is to submit spam or phishing samples for forensic analysis, attach the entire message as a `message/rfc822` MIME part, and put comments etc in a separate MIME part.

Comment: As an aside, it looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: I learned every one sample in the email: Examples

Comment: Not sure what that means. Python pre-3.6 had code similar to yours in the `examples` documentation because that's what the API looked like then. There are unfortunately many, many other web pages which still recommend the old API because they were written before 3.6

Comment: I used https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html At the top of the page they say it is 3.10.5 Documentation

Comment: Indeed, that document uses `EmailMessage`, not the legacy API you use in your question (called "compat32" in the new docs).